# Cron command to run PHP script every 10 minute

Tags: cron

In my hosting i have a section for cron job like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [site-helper.com](http://www.site-helper.com/gs99.gif))</sub>

The PHP script is called "croned.php", which I want it to run every 10 minutes.

What I will fill in every field?

I tried but it didn't work.

Note: the full path to the script is: /home/axelzd/domains/hellodom.com/public_html/croned.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can use commas to separate the cron minutes/hours etc. - `0,10,20,30,40,50` in your  minute field (but I can't guarantee your admin will take it - I know Plesk does) and `*` in all others .  The command is more tricky, but something like this should do `/usr/bin/wget -q -t 5 --delete-after URL_TO_YOUR_CRON` or `php PATH_TO_YOUR_PHP_FILE_ON_THE_SERVER`

Answer (score 8):

Put `*/10` in the minutes whilst putting `*` in all other fields.

Comment: did not know about the `*/10` syntax - will save some typing

Comment: the best way, IMHO. This syntax was done especially for this situation. Silly not to use stantard sintax

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
*/10 * * * * <command_to_be_invoked>
```